# How to see if a disk is full in WPA or PerfView

Tags: debugging, etw, xperf, perfview, windows-performance-analyzer

I am using WPA and PerfView to capture traces to diagnose why an IIS server hanged.
We have reasons to believe that at the time one of the disk was **completely full**.

Is there a way to see in these tools (WPA, PerfView) how full the disks are?

We get a lot of useful and detailed information out of the tool but I fail to find just this simple metric.

Thank you!

Comment: I see some data in WPA->system configuration->storage. Here I can see free clusters

Comment: That gave me the information I needed @magicandre1981 How can I accept your answer? Thank you

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: is question answered or do you still need more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Windows Performance Analyzer` shows the free Clusters from the Windows [Kernel/SystemConfig/LogDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/systemconfig-logdisk) Event in System Configuration/Storage:

[image]

To see it in Perfview, search for LogDisk Event:

[image]